# How to create sitemap.xml.gz in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, seo, sitemap, google-search-console

How to create `sitemap.xml.gz` in laravel ?

Is `.gz` essential for Google Webmasters? Or just `sitemap.xml` is enough.

Is there a useful library to create this?

Comment: @Machavity it not duplicate! i want compress sitemap!!

Comment: @Will it not duplicate! i want compress sitemap!!

Comment: This is a very different question than what is marked as duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

.gz is not required, just sitemap.xml for google developers is fine.

Check out this package, it might do the trick
https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sitemap

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But i want compress it. this package not support.